# Issue while using (.loc) with in keyword

Tags: python, pandas

I am using in keyword with df.loc[] and getting error.

```
missing_value=['a','b']
df=df.loc[df['Alpha'] in missing_value]
```

How can this be accomplished, using pandas(.loc)?

Comment: `df.loc` is no function/method, but a view that can be indexed. Maybe `df.loc[...]` is what you are looking for.

Comment: when I am using in keyword inside .loc then I am getting.

Comment: `df[df['Alpha'].isin(missing_value)]` is what you are looking for.

Comment: @BenPap I already tried this but I am not getting the result which I expect from in keyword yes but using this my error removed.

Comment: Then give us example data, the error messages you are getting and the result you are expecting.